# WPF application freezes on ToolTip (only inside Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, visual-studio-2017

After upgrading a **VS2010** WPF project (that uses unmanaged code as well if that matters) to **VS2017** (along with some other other upgrades such as Cuda), when running the application, everything works until a tooltip is required to appear. 
The weird thing is that **this only happens when running the code with a debugger** (inside VS), but **when running without it works fine** (Ctrl+F5, or the .exe directly) .

The Tooltip is a simple textbox ToolTip (Adding `ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000"` makes the freeze delay in 5 seconds).

Pausing the application when the freeze occurs, a stack trace of the Main thread shows that the app is stuck on a `WaitForSingleObject` in `ntdll.dll` after a `RaiseToolTipOpeningEvent` is triggered (I'm assuming the parts before that are related to WPF's mechanism for raising the tool tip with a slight delay).

Here's the stack:

```
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx() Unknown Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CDllHost::MTAInitializeActivators() Line 830    C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CDllHost::GetApartmentActivators(unsigned long & hCOMActivator, unsigned long & hWinRTActivator) Line 622   C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] combase.dll!CDllHost::GetCOMApartmentActivator(unsigned long &) Line 133 C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] combase.dll!DoATApartmentCreate(unsigned long &) Line 225    C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CClassCache::GetActivatorFromDllHost(int fSixteenBit, int isActivatingAppInstalledClass, unsigned long dwDllThreadModel, unsigned long * phActivator) Line 3643 C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CProcessActivator::GetApartmentActivator(ActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, ISystemActivator * * ppActivator) Line 1093 C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CProcessActivator::CCICallback(unsigned long dwContext, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 1601   C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation(ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties, HRESULT(CProcessActivator::*)(unsigned long, IUnknown *, ActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesOut * *) pfnCtxActCallback, unsigned long dwContext) Line 1524  C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext(ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties, HRESULT(CProcessActivator::*)(unsigned long, IUnknown *, ActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesIn *, IActivationPropertiesOut * *) pfnCtxActCallback) Line 1368   C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 1268  C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppActPropsOut) Line 1932  C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesIn * pInActProperties, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppOutActProperties) Line 567 C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance(IUnknown * pUnkOuter, IActivationPropertiesOut * * ppActPropsOut) Line 1984  C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!ICoCreateInstanceEx(const _GUID & OriginalClsid, IUnknown * punkOuter, unsigned long dwClsCtx, _COSERVERINFO * pServerInfo, unsigned long dwCount, unsigned long dwActvFlags, tagMULTI_QI * pResults, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn) Line 1935    C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CComActivator::DoCreateInstance(const _GUID & Clsid, IUnknown * punkOuter, unsigned long dwClsCtx, _COSERVERINFO * pServerInfo, unsigned long dwCount, tagMULTI_QI * pResults, ActivationPropertiesIn * pActIn) Line 385    C++ Symbols loaded.
[Inline Frame] combase.dll!CoCreateInstanceEx(const _GUID &) Line 176   C++ Symbols loaded.
combase.dll!CoCreateInstance(const _GUID & rclsid, IUnknown * pUnkOuter, unsigned long dwContext, const _GUID & riid, void * * ppv) Line 120    C++ Symbols loaded.
PGHook.dll!00007ffd375410a4()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
UIAutomationCore.dll!BlockingCoreDispatcher::CreateAndRegisterBlockingCore(void)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
UIAutomationCore.dll!BlockingCoreDispatcher::FinalConstruct(void)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
UIAutomationCore.dll!CUIAutomation7::FinalConstruct(void)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
UIAutomationCore.dll!ATL::CComObject<class CUIAutomation7>::CreateInstance(class ATL::CComObject<class CUIAutomation7> * *) Unknown Symbols loaded.
UIAutomationCore.dll!UiaReturnRawElementProvider() Unknown Symbols loaded.
UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll!00007ffd1ab2a933()  Unknown No symbols loaded.
[Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
UIAutomationProvider.dll!System.Windows.Automation.Provider.AutomationInteropProvider.ReturnRawElementProvider(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IRawElementProviderSimple el) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.PopupSecurityHelper.ForceMsaaToUiaBridge(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PopupRoot popupRoot) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(bool asyncCall) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(System.Windows.DependencyObject target, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.Data.BindingBase binding)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateRootPopup(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup, System.Windows.UIElement child)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.OnIsOpenChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.RaiseToolTipOpeningEvent()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(object unused)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 954  C#  Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 902  C#  Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 891    C#  Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.ni.dll!00007ffce783bd98()   Unknown No symbols loaded.
[Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
MyApplication.exe!MyApplication.App.Main()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
mscoreei.dll!_CorExeMain() Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscoree.dll!_CorExeMain_Exported() Unknown Symbols loaded.
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown Symbols loaded.
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown Symbols loaded.
```

I can't find any thread that's blocking the main thread by not signaling the above waited object. I've tried returning to .NET 4.5.1 (Now using 4.7) but it had no effect.

When running the executable directly and attaching to the process, it works fine as well, so I compared the modules used when loading with debugger and without, and somehow `ntdll.dll` is not even loaded when running without a debugger (which is even more confusing to me).

Searching the web led me no where so any help or suggestion would be appreciated.